# Button not showing up in run as in preview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so i have a button whos XAML is as follows:

```
    <Grid>
    <!--MoreCode -->
        <Button x:Name="Camera2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="images\tabNormal.png"></Image>
                <Image Source="images\OfflineRed_21x76.png" Height="18" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5"></Image>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Camera 2"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    <!--MoreCode -->
    </Grid>
```

and it Previews ok.

[image: Button in preview]

But when i Run the project I get this:

[image: PlainButton]

In the end I will end up making this button a standard control, but i want to understand why it does not seem to build right when I run.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The designer view can be misleading sometimes. You tried run your app after commented the textblock and leave only the 2 images? Works fine?

Comment: yeah, no dice there either, still missing images. Tried with removing all but one image and still nothing

Comment: Can you post an image of your WPF project of the "solution explorer" view on Visual Studio showing the locations of your Window (where the button is) and your images?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, this fit?

Comment: ok, but show also where are the locations of the other 2 images (tabNormal.png and OfflineRed_21x76.png) and where are those 2 files relative to the ShellView.xaml. The problem, I think, is because the path of the images are not being set correctly (Sorry my bad english)

Comment: there is an images folder in the same views folder as the xaml files they are in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212811/discussion-between-marlonchosky-and-levi-clouser).

Answer (score 0):

in Closing, the problem seemed to be something with the compiler not referencing the images properly (perhaps because I added the images folder to the project after building everything?), the solution was to add the full path to the images i.e. `C:\...folders...\images\filename.png` as opposed to the initial `images\filename.png` once this was done once for one file all files in that folder are readable and you can return to a relitive location. Everything seems to be working fine now even after deleting and re adding the files/folder

Comment: Wait, I thought that your answer for this question was other than this. It's a really bad idea to set an absolute path like this in your application. What happen if your change the directory or move the project?

Comment: i changed the path back and everything is ok now

Comment: Ok, update your answer, telling that you back your sources as relatives path